# Android: How to get Newly sent Sms Data but not with URI

Tags: android, sms, toast

I want to get sent sms data but only single sms which has been sent from device. Using URI i can get all SMS data but i dont want to get all SMS data again and again.
I am able to get newly received sms data and Toasting it with`BroadcastReciever` but I dont know how to get newly sent sms data and toast it.
Here is my code to get recieved sms data:

```
public class incomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);

                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    Date date = new Date(currentMessage.getTimestampMillis());
                    String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(date);

                    long time=date.getTime();
                    String formattedTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(time);

                    Toast.makeText(context,"recieved sms "+"senderNum: "+ phoneNumber + ", message: " + message+ " , date:" + formattedDate + ",time: "+formattedTime , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                    MyDBHandler db = new MyDBHandler(context);

                    int f_id=1;
                    db.insertDat2(new DataSetGet(f_id,phoneNumber,message,formattedDate,formattedTime));
//                    addData(phoneNumber,message,formattedDate,formattedTime);

                } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }


        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;


        if (bundle != null) {

            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i=0; i < msgs.length; i++) {

                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

                String no = "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress() + " : ";
                String message= msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                Toast.makeText(context,"sent message "+"no: "+no+" message: "+ message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard broadcast regarding sent SMS messages.

Comment: Then How can i get it??

Comment: @UzairQaiser: On Android 7.0+, use `JobScheduler` [and `addTriggerContentUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#addTriggerContentUri(android.app.job.JobInfo.TriggerContentUri)), perhaps. Or, while your process is running, register a `ContentObserver`.

Comment: perhaps means you dont know perfectly?

Comment: @UzairQaiser: Perhaps means that I have not tried `addTriggerContentUri()` with the `Sms` provider, and since Android 4.4, that provider is a bit strange. Presumably, with `READ_SMS`, you can use `addTriggerContentUri()` just fine.